# Anonymous Animation with Animation Listener

Tags: android, animation

I would like to have an Anonymous Animation with Animation Listener. What I am trying to achieve is to create an animation type on fly and set Animation Listener to it which will hide or show View based on parameter. Following is my Listener.

```
public class MyAnimationListener implements AnimationListener
    {

        private LinearLayout mLinerLayout;
        private int mVisibility;

        public MyAnimationListener(LinearLayout l,int visiblity) {
            mLinerLayout = l;
            mVisibility = visiblity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
        {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            mLinerLayout.setVisibility(mVisibility);
        }
    }
```

I want to do something like following where I can assign Anonymous Animation with my Listener

```
lnrLayoutWebsite.startAnimation(/*new Animation(){with my listener here}*/);
```

I know I could have done following and could have achieved the result. But lets say I have 20 Views for which I need to create some Anonymous Animations.

```
slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);
slideUp.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(lnrLayoutWebsite, View.GONE));
lnrLayoutWebsite.startAnimation(slideUp);
```

how can I achieve what I described above?

Comment: i dont see any question mark here... so what is your question actually?

Comment: @pskink: check now please

Comment: I would say just forget making an anonymous object and create a local one within the method.  It achieves the same result

Comment: @DeeV: I have few other animations going on at the same time. I cannot use the same "slideUp" object with setAnimationListener set for each layout differently, hence I was looking for anonymous animation object so I don't have to create variables like slideUp1, slideUp2, slideUp3...

`lnrLayoutPhone.startAnimation(slideUp);
lnrLayoutWebsite.startAnimation(slideUp);
lnrLayoutAltitude.startAnimation(slideUp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with anonymous statements. What you can do though is create a helper method like this:

```
public static Animation createAnimation() {    
  Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up); 
  slideUp.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(lnrLayoutWebsite, View.GONE));
  return slideUp; 
}
```

Then simply add new animations like this:

```
lnrLayoutWebsite.startAnimation(createAnimation());
```

This also holds the advantage of being able to easily modify the Animation by passing in parameters to the change certain things if you want.  Or simply changing the entire animation being returned.

Comment: Thanks @DeeV. I was able to find my answer. You are right, anonymous method is not the option here.

Answer (score 1):

------------------------ ANSWER ------------------------

I was able to find the answer with some help from @DeeV. Create a method like below and use the Listener above:

```
private void slideUpDownAnimation(View mView , int mVisibility)
{
    Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_down);
    Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_up);

    switch (mVisibility)
        {
        case View.GONE:
            slideUp.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(mView,mVisibility));
            mView.startAnimation(slideUp);
            break;

        case View.VISIBLE:
            slideDown.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener(mView,mVisibility));
            mView.startAnimation(slideDown);
            break;
        }
}
```

And then slide up or down based on your preference:

```
slideUpDownAnimation(lnrLayoutPhone,View.GONE);
slideUpDownAnimation(lnrLayoutWebsite,View.VISIBLE);
slideUpDownAnimation(lnrLayoutEmail,View.VISIBLE);
```